# Mathematica program for PLUR decomposition of a symbolic matrix using full pivoting

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I wanted to ask if there is a Mathematica program for PLUR decomposition of a symbolic matrix M, such that M = P*L*U*R, using FULL (row and column) pivoting, and where R = reduced row echelon form of M.

The entries of the matrix M are rational numbers, floating point numbers and symbolic expressions.

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality. Also not clear why one might want it in the symbolic case.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am not sure if it exists now, but for your information, a symbolic PLUR decomposition can be used to determined whether all parameters can be identified (estimated) in some statistical model.

Comment: What is the gain from column pivoting in the symbolic case? Is this to move pivots to earlier columns? If so, that can be done with column swaps of the reduced echelon form from `RowReduce`.