# Factorize trigonometric matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, trigonometry, factorization

Consider two square matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$. Consider the following matrix involving matrix trigonometric functions:

\begin{equation}
M_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(tA_1) & t\mathrm{sinc}(t A_1) \\ -A_1\sin(tA_1) & \cos(tA_1) \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
and similarly $M_2(t)$ defined by changing $A_1$ to $A_2$. Using the double-angle identities, it can be shown that

\begin{align}
\delta &= M_1(2t_1)-M_2(2t_2) \\
&= 2\begin{bmatrix} t_1\mathrm{sinc}(t_1A_1) & -t_2\mathrm{sinc}(t_2A_2) \\ \cos (t_1 A_1) & -\cos(t_2A_2) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-A_1\sin(t_1A_1) & \cos(t_1 A_1) \\ -A_2\sin(t_2A_2) & \cos(t_2 A_2) \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

which provides a factorization of the difference $\delta$.

This equality can be checked in MMA using random values for $A_1,A_2,t_1,t_2$:

```
M1[t_] := 
 ArrayFlatten[{{MatrixFunction[Cos, t*A1], 
    t*MatrixFunction[Sinc, t*A1]}, {-A1.MatrixFunction[Sin, t*A1], 
    MatrixFunction[Cos, t*A1]}}]
M2[t_] := 
 ArrayFlatten[{{MatrixFunction[Cos, t*A2], 
    t*MatrixFunction[Sinc, t*A2]}, {-A2.MatrixFunction[Sin, t*A2], 
    MatrixFunction[Cos, t*A2]}}]
delta := M1[2 t1] - M2[2 t2]
zero := delta - 
  2 ArrayFlatten[{{t1*MatrixFunction[Sinc, t1*A1], -t2*
        MatrixFunction[Sinc, t2*A2]}, {MatrixFunction[Cos, 
        t1*A1], -MatrixFunction[Cos, 
         t2*A2]}}].ArrayFlatten[{{-A1.MatrixFunction[Sin, t1*A1], 
       MatrixFunction[Cos, t1*A1]}, {-A2.MatrixFunction[Sin, t2*A2], 
       MatrixFunction[Cos, t2*A2]}}]

Block[{A1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}], 
   A2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}], t1 = RandomReal[10], 
   t2 = RandomReal[10]}, zero] // Chop

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

My question is, would it have been possible to find this factorization using MMA?

Comment: There is an infinity of matrix products that equal `δ`.  What is the criterion for selecting the one in the question?

Comment: @bbgodfrey In the question I ask to find _this_ precise factorization. The reason is that $\det \delta = 1$ iff at least one of the two matrices of the factorized form is singular. Having $\delta = I_n \delta$ would not be useful. Here, it provides a factorization of $\det\delta$. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I doubt your were asking for that level of detail, but this factorization is associated with a very nice physical interpretation (in short, symmetry of some motions of impact oscillators), see [this article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01505888/document), near equation (3.15) --- unfortunately I can't think of a short explanation... It is used to find [such motions](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01505888/).

Comment: Are $ A_1 $ and $ A_2 $ simultaneouly diagonalizable?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςZεγγ unfortunately not...

Comment: I was thinking about making use of $ \sigma_i \sigma_j = \delta_{ij} \sigma_0 + \mathrm i \varepsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k $ yesterday; but still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I did the problem in reverse and showed the matrix product (which I called `δ2`) reduces to the difference of matrices with

```
δ2 // FunctionExpand // Simplify
```

Only then I could reduce the `Sinc[A]` as `Sin[A]/A`. The result is that of a difference of two matrices.

Comment: OK but my question was on factorizing, not expanding :)

Answer (score -2):

this is a question with some answer that might interest You:

[mathematica program for PLUR decomposition of a symbolic matrix using full pivot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46152/mathematica-program-for-plur-decomposition-of-a-symbolic-matrix-using-full-pivot).

Nobody needs it, nobody wants it following [@daniel-lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau).

For numerical decomposition, You have the choices in Mathematica: [AdvancedMatrixOperations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedMatrixOperations.html).

The major problem atop is that

```
InverseFunction[Sinc[x]]
```

(*InverseFunction[Sinc[x]]*)

is not a function pair like `Sin/ArcSin` are. And that is even worse because this is the `MatrixFunction` of `Sinc`.

Simple example: rotation

```
{Q, R} = QRDecomposition[{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
(* {{{1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}, {{Sqrt[2],0}, {0, Sqrt[2]}}} *)
```

and

```
Solve[RotationMatrix[\[CurlyPhi] ] == Q, \[CurlyPhi]][[1]] /.C[1] -> 0 
(*{\[CurlyPhi] -> \[Pi]/4} *)
```

A simple example: regular matrix

```
S = MatrixPower[Transpose[M].M, 1/2]; R = Inverse[Transpose[M]].S(* rotationmatrix R^t.R=Identity*)
```

A variation:

```
m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
FullSimplify @ Solve[ConjugateTranspose[RotationMatrix[θ]].ScalingMatrix[{s1, s2}] == m, 
  {s1, s2, θ}, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0
```

As far as I understand the given source:

[periodic solutions of n-dof autonomous vibro-impact oscillators with one lasting contact phase](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01505888/document)

There are three matrices:

```
M={{m1,0},{0,m2}} (*mass matrix*)
```

and

K={{k1+k2,-k2},{-k2,k2}} (*coupling matrix of harmonic oscillators*)

both from formular (2.5)

and

A={{0,I},{-L^2,0}}

from (3.9).

This A matrix is then put into the `MatrixExp` to give (3.11) and (3.12). In both of them L is a scalar out of `Reals`. And that remains in all the following sections.

This seems together with the commend more or less the solution path to the proof of theorem 3.1 Please reformulate.

Comment: PLUR seems to be unrelated to the question that was asked.